# Reversing A String. Every other word reversing

Tags: java, string

So i've got a for loop that's reversing every other word in a string. I can't determine which condition is causing this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) 
{
    stringBuilder.append(words[(words.length-1)-i]);
    stringBuilder.reverse()
}
newMessage = stringBuilder.toString();
return Message
```

Answer (score 2):

`stringBuilder.reverse()` reverse the whole string that you are currently building at each iteration.

Try:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < words.length ; i++) {
    String word = words[(words.length-1)-i];
    String reverse = new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString();
    stringBuilder.append(reverse).append(" ");
}
```

Or even simpler, reversing at the end:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < words.length ; i++) {
    stringBuilder.append(words[(words.length-1)-i]).append(" ");
}
newMessage = stringBuilder.reverse().toString();
```

### Edit based on comments:

```
for (String w : words) {
    String reverse = new StringBuilder(w).reverse().toString();
    stringBuilder.append(reverse).append(" ");
}
newMessage = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: The goal is to keep the word positioning, but reverse the words.

Ex: Hello World is olleh dlrow

Comment: I added the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. I'll make sure to commit this to memory

Answer (score 0):

stringBuilder.reverse(); is reversing the whole word comment that line and your code wont reverse your new message

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your loop is more complex then it needs to be. If you want to reverse words starting from the end, you should just use the loop index to do that, you don't need the `(words.length-1)-i` calculation.

Another thing, when you call `reverse()` on a `StringBuilder` you are reversing the whole string not just the appended portion. What you can do is use a temp `StringBuilder` to perform the reversal and a temp `String` variable to separate reversal from appending.

Something like this:

```
StringBuilder reversedBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i --) 
{
    String reversed = reversedBuilder.append(words[i]).reverse().toString(); // reverse the word
    stringBuilder.append(reversed).append(" ");
    reversedBuilder.setLength(0); // clear the reversed
}
```

If you want, you can do this in a single line of code (added with comments for clarification):

```
for (int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i --) 
{
    stringBuilder.append(new StringBuilder()  // create a temp string builder
                            .append(words[i]) // add the current word to temp string builder
                            .reverse()        // reverse the current word in the temp string builder
                            .toString())      // add the reversed word to stringBuilder
                 .append(" ");                // add the space to stringBuilder
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "hello world";

function reverseWords(string) {
   var words = string.split(' '),
   finals = [];

   words.forEach(function(word) {
     finals.push(word.split('').reverse().join(''););
   });

   return finals.join(' ');
 }

 reverseWords(string); // "olleh dlrow"
```